# Use Azure ML Environment from Share ML Registry with Python SDK

Tags: python-3.x, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-sdk-python, azureml-python-sdk, azure-ml-pipelines

We have created an environment in azure ML shared registry. The environment was built into the registry. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

A DevOps pipeline creates this environment:

```
az ml environment create --name "$azureEnvPrefix" --build-context $dockerContext --dockerfile-path Dockerfile --registry-name $REGISTRY_NAME --tag "dev-$timestamp producer-CI"
```

The environment seems fine. But, when we use the same environment in ml pipeline using:

```
try:
    cred = ManagedIdentityCredential()
    ml_client_registry = MLClient(credential=cred,
                        registry_name=e.registry_name,
                        registry_location=e.registry_region)
    registyr_envs = [env for env in ml_client_registry.environments.list(e.monitoring)]
except Exception as e:
    print("Unable to get environment")
    raise e
environment_monitoring = ml_client_registry.environments.get(name=monitoring, version=registyr_envs[0].version)
```

It works but using this environment with runconfig for a **PythonScriptStep** results in error:

```
run_config_monitoring = RunConfiguration()
run_config_monitoring.environment = environment_monitoring

param_actuals_feature_name = PipelineParameter(
    name='actuals_feature_name', default_value='payment_amt_acc')

StepMonitoring = PythonScriptStep(
    script_name=e.script_path,
    arguments=["--actuals_feature_name", param_actuals_feature_name],
    source_directory=e.sources_directory,
    name='Monitoring',
    compute_target=aml_compute_cpu,
    allow_reuse=False,
    runconfig=run_config_monitoring
)

step_sequence = StepSequence(steps=[StepMonitoring])
pipeline = Pipeline(workspace=ws, steps=step_sequence)
```

It results in error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/anaconda/envs/localpy38/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in
> _run_module_as_main
> return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "/anaconda/envs/localpy38/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in
> _run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)   File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/ourrehmansweden/code/Users/ourrehman/Sweden_cashflow_forecasting_aml/ml_service/pipelines/build_pipeline_active_monitoring.py",
> line 157, in 
> main(args)   File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/ourrehmansweden/code/Users/ourrehman/Sweden_cashflow_forecasting_aml/ml_service/pipelines/build_pipeline_active_monitoring.py",
> line 70, in main
> environment_active_monitoring = ml_client_registry.environments.get(name=e.aml_env_name_active_monitoring,
> version=registyr_envs[0].version)   File
> "/anaconda/envs/localpy38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/core/_experiment_method.py",
> line 104, in wrapper
> return init_func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/anaconda/envs/localpy38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/core/pipeline.py",
> line 180, in **init**
> self._graph = self._graph_builder.build(self._name, steps, finalize=False)   File
> "/anaconda/envs/localpy38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/core/builder.py",
> line 1497, in build
> graph = self.construct(name, steps)   File "/anaconda/envs/localpy38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/core/builder.py",
> line 1519, in construct
> self.process_collection(steps)   File "/anaconda/envs/localpy38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/core/builder.py",
> line 1555, in process_collection
> builder.process_collection(collection)   File "/anaconda/envs/localpy38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/core/builder.py",
> line 1809, in process_collection
> nodes = self._base_builder.process_collection(item)   File "/anaconda/envs/localpy38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/core/builder.py",
> line 1549, in process_collection
> return self.process_step(collection)   File "/anaconda/envs/localpy38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/core/builder.py",
> line 1593, in process_step
> node = step.create_node(self._graph, self._default_datastore, self._context)   File
> "/anaconda/envs/localpy38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/steps/python_script_step.py",
> line 243, in create_node
> return super(PythonScriptStep, self).create_node(   File "/anaconda/envs/localpy38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/core/_python_script_step_base.py",
> line 156, in create_node
> module_builder=module_builder, runconfig=repr(self._runconfig))   File
> "/anaconda/envs/localpy38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/core/runconfig.py",
> line 1352, in **repr**
> run_config_dict = _serialize_to_dict(self)   File "/anaconda/envs/localpy38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/core/_serialization_utils.py",
> line 44, in _serialize_to_dict
> result[name] = field_info.field_type._serialize_to_dict(   File "/anaconda/envs/localpy38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/core/environment.py",
> line 1685, in _serialize_to_dict
> if environment.python.conda_dependencies is not None: **AttributeError: 'Environment' object has no attribute 'python'**

I see that the code which complains is **azureml/core/environment.py", line 1685**:

```
if environment is not None and not isinstance(environment, EnvironmentReference):
    if environment.python.conda_dependencies is not None:
        inline = environment.python.conda_dependencies._conda_dependencies
        environment_dict["python"]["condaDependencies"] = inline
```

Is there something that I am missing, or we can't use environments like this? Would be thankful if anyone could help!